# How do I switch from Bitcoin-QT to a lighter, faster (SPV) Bitcoin client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat, bip37-bloom-filter, spv

So, keeping up to date with the blockchain is getting ridiculous in Bitcoin-QT, especially on my laptop.  If I leave it off or away from the internet for even a short period of time, it takes **forever** to catch up.

But, fortunately, the Bitcoin network allows for a simpler model, called [Simplified Payment Verification](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Thin_Client_Security#Simplified_Payment_Verification_.28SPV.29) (or SPV) mode where only the headers of blocks are needed.  In addition, the Bitcoin network has recently been updated to support [bloom filtering](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0037) so that a client only needs to download the transactions that it is interested in (plus some margin for privacy).

First question:  **Is there a client capable of importing my Bitcoin-QT wallet that supports these two options?** (and preferably has a light resource footprint if I'm not asking too much)

And secondly, if so, **how can I accomplish the switch with minimal pain?**

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, your solution is the MultiBit Wallet software - it should satisfy all your requirements: https://multibit.org/index.html

I use it on a regular basis and found it satisfying, and also have the possibility of storing more than one wallet, you should give it a try.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you explain how one switches a wallet over to multibit?

Comment: Simply send the bitcoins from the old wallet to the new, multibit address. If you are not concerned about the small fee, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The least painful way is to let go of your old wallet, as long as you know that nothing else will be ever coming to you on any of those addresses. Simply start the new client and send your balance to one if its new addresses.

If you must hold onto your old addresses, look for a client that can import the Bitcoin-Qt exports. I believe that MultiBit can do this.

Comment: You've hit the nail on the head--this wallet holds addresses that are widely distributed in non-updateable locations and may continue receiving deposits.  How does one go about importing into MultiBit?

Comment: To import into multibit, first create an new wallet in multibit. Then choose "Export private keys" and don't set a password. Edit the .key file and enter your real private key instead. Save and import back in to multibit.